# Role="presentation" with <form> inside

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation">
            <form action="/logout" method="POST" id="logout-form">
                <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit()">Logout</a>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The design for the link with the form is not correct. Does anybody have an idea what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is very obvious...

```
<form action="/logout" method="POST" id="logout-form"></form>

<li role="presentation">
    <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit()">Logout</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
```